# Como gerar um código único para cada aparelho?

Tags: android

Preciso fazer um sorteio e para isso tem que ser gerado um código único para cada aparelho. Mesmo desinstalando e reinstalando o app,o código gerado tem que ser sempre o mesmo.

Como solucionar isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMEI pode não ser uma boa alternativa, pois alguns tablets não tem, além de precisar de permissão do usuário pra acessar. A Google tem um artigo muito bom sobre isso: 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Uma solução pro seu caso, poderia ser concatenar alguns dos ID's descritos no artigo, como por exemplo o Serial (android.os.Build.SERIAL) e o Android ID (Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID), ou gerar uma UUID a partir de um md5 destas ID's.

Comment: Olá,isso viola algum termo do google play ? Ouvi falar que não pode colocar isso se não por nos termos,correto ?

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta, mas se está falando das permissões de acesso ao IMEI, é só colocar no manifest mesmo. Mas acho que o maior problema em usar o IMEI  são os tablets que só tem wi-fi, pois eles não tem IMEI.

Comment: Acho que a melhor solução pra ti seria usar a  ANDROID_ID (Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID), mas alguns aparelhos saíram com esse ID bugado (leia o link no post), então, acho que seria melhour usar o ANDROID_ID concatenado com a Build.SERIAL. E se quiser mais segurança ainda pode concatenar o IMEI junto.

Comment: Obrigado,irei concatenar os 2,Agradeço a atenção

Answer (score 2):

Você pode [usar o IMEI do aparelho](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId()) pra isso.

O problema é que um usuário avançado, ou uma manutenção de celulares, pode alterar o IMEI, aí depende do nível de confiabilidade necessário para a sua aplicação, para a maioria é o suficiente já que se o usuário fizer isso, ele sabe que é por conta e risco próprio. Mas como o Emerson falou em outra resposta, se você também estiver fazendo esse app para tablets ou qualquer outro tipo de aparelho android que não use a rede celular, o IMEI não é uma boa opção.

Comment: Obrigado pelas Dicas :)